# How to store data in each ms in simulink to a vector variable

Tags: vector, simulink, scalar

In my simulink model :
I am getting a variable acceleration data (0.2232, 0.221, 0.210, 0.225, 0.2231 and so on) which is a scalar for 500ms. My sample time is 1ms. So I need to store each of this data (which is always changing) in a vector (for 500ms). How can I achieve this in Simulink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a data store write(as a buffer) and an index value and assignment block to generate an array.